# How do you create a big array?

Tags: java, arrays, long-integer

I notice that when you create an array, it can only go up to the size of an int since that is the only thing it accepts. How do I create one that fits the size of a long?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071858/java-creating-byte-array-whose-size-is-represented-by-a-long

Comment: Why you need such a big array? It seems there is a design problem.

Comment: You could do multidimensional array of Integer.MAX_VALUE-1 for each dimension, but that would be the end of your memory.

Comment: One wonders what actual need would be served by allocating memory for more than 2 billion elements.  When dealing with such large datasets, the best solution often is to filter your data with queries first and then deal with the smaller and more efficient result sets.

Comment: @Drogba At first, I needed that big of an array, but then I figured an alternative. Now I just got to figure out how to use the math.sqrt() method with a long. Any ideas?

Comment: @dalawh You can pass a `long` to `Math.sqrt`. It should work.

Comment: holding that many of records in memory is just asking for trouble. should redesign using some kind of streaming pattern

Answer (score 4):

You could use a two-dimensional array.

E.g.

```
Object[][] objects = new Object[Integer.MAX_VALUE][Integer.MAX_VALUE];
```

Comment: FYI, that would consume about 4 exabytes of memory.  Good luck.

Comment: It is only an example ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Java arrays are limited to `int` indices, by the Java language specification. (See [section 10.4, "Array Access"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4).)

Allowing `long` indices was [proposed as part of Project Coin](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000869.html), prior to Java 7, but the proposal [was not accepted](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_final_five).

An alternative is to use an object representing a vector of elements that supports a long index.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Java Language Specification (see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html), you may only index into an array using a `int` (or a `short`, `byte`, or `char`, which are treated as `int` for this purpose).

Bear in mind that the need to index into an array using a long assumes that you will have > ~2 gigs of available **contiguous** memory.  Depending on your garbage collection strategy and your total allocated memory, this may be difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can only create a BigArray class based on several arrays and which will have set / get methods with long arguments.