# Java: Size limitation on direct IntBuffer?

Tags: java, bytebuffer, addressing

I want to allocate a **direct** IntBuffer in Java with, say, a billion elements (64-bit system). The only way I know of is creating a direct ByteBuffer and viewing it as a direct IntBuffer. However, 4*1,000,000,000 exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE, so my question is: how can I achieve my goal?

```
int numInts = 1_000_000_000;
IntBuffer i = IntBuffer.allocate(numInts); // works!

ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*numInts); // does NOT work: integer overflow
IntBuffer ib = bb.asIntBuffer();
System.out.println("This will never be printed");
```

Thanks a lot in advance,

Markus

Comment: how about creating a two dimensional array of buffers ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java creating byte array whose size is represented by a long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071858/java-creating-byte-array-whose-size-is-represented-by-a-long)

Comment: It's not a limitation with IntBuffer, it's a java limititaon. Arrays length in java cannot be bigger than 2^31.

Comment: You're right, but my buffer's size need not exceed 2^31 integers, the problem arises because of the (necessary?) detour via ByteBuffer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to create a Buffer based on a BigInteger instead. Some people created a 'BigIntbuffer' class on Github that could inspire you :
[See here](https://github.com/senseidb/bobo/blob/master/bobo-browse/src/main/java/com/browseengine/bobo/util/BigIntBuffer.java)